# Get an associative parameter array for a function defined without predefined function parameters

Tags: php

Is it possible to get an associative parameter array for a function defined without predefined function parameters.

Lets assume the following function:

```php
function foo()
{
   print_r(func_get_args());
}
```

Example:

```php
$a = "bar";
$b = "baz";

foo($a, $b);
```

Results in:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => "bar"
    [1] => "baz"
)
```

The desired outcome would be:

```php
Array
(
    [a] => "bar"
    [b] => "baz"
)
```

Tried so far:

PHP's ReflectionFunction will only return **foo**'s predefined parameters, not its dynamically defined parameters.

Comment: Can you use an associative array for $a and $b? And calling your function with something likes that array('a' => 'bar', 'b' => 'baz')?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible by passing an associative array as a parameter:

```
<?php
function foo(array $args = array()) {
    print_r($args);
}

foo(
    array(
    'a' => 'bar',
    'b' => 'baz'
    )
);
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [a] => bar
    [b] => baz
)
```

And with defined parameters, you can try get_defined_vars(). "*Returns an array in which each element is a copy of the corresponding member of the current user-defined function's argument list.*"

```
<?php
function foo($a, $b)
{
   print_r(get_defined_vars());
}
$a = "bar";
$b = "baz";

foo($a, $b);
```

Results:
Array

```
(
    [a] => bar
    [b] => baz
)
```

Comment: @Gijs, does this answer your question?

Comment: sadly it does not, this takes away the "without predefined function parameters" element. You solution will work if you are willing to use an array as single argument. Thanks for replying!